# Существует ли функция проверки существования файла?

Tags: php

Подскажите есть ли такая функция чтобы она обрабатывала ссылку типа "http://anysite.ru/image.jpg" и возвращала 'true' если эта картинка существует и 'false' если не существует?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**file_exists**

```
file_exists('путь к файлу'); //если файл существует вернет true и false если файла нет
```

и не забывайте о том что путь пишется серверный а не http, т.е. чтото типа `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/someimg.jpg'` вместо `http://siteName/img/someimg.jpg`

Если речь идет о файлах на других сайтах
Как вариант пытаться получить изображение `file_get_contents`, занести в переменную и проверить на "пустоту..."

В случае именно с картинками наверное лучше использовать `getimagesize()` там собственно не суть зачем она на самом деле нужна, вообщем вот пример кода с `getimagesize()`:

```
$img = getimagesize('http://somesite/someimg');
if($img) {
     //все ок :)
}
else {
    //печаль :( причем даже если прийдет чтото но это не будет картинкой
    //всеравно будет печаль...
}
```

Небольшое пояснение почему - если например на сайте сделана нестандартная 404 то в `file_get_contents` у нас законно будет инфа, но при этому изображения то нет :) Вероятность этому небольшая, но если программист для "нестандартной страницы 404"  установил заголовок 404 - то и так все будет впорядке, но лично я считаю что лучше перебдеть чем недобдеть ^^...
кстати результатом отработки этой функции в случае существования изображения - массив с инфой о картинке: высоте, ширине и формате.

ну и пример с `file_get_contents`...

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://somesite/someimg');
if($img) {
    // не факт что картинка но чтото есть :)
}
else {
    // пусто...
}
```

Comment: А если сайт другой?

Comment: сторонний

Comment: "не факт что картинка, но что то есть :))" - мем))

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents('http: и.т.д');